# Decoding a FlateDecoded section of text in a PDF document

Tags: pdf, ms-word, deflate, textedit, pdf-parsing

Using [peepdf](https://code.google.com/p/peepdf/) I am analyzing two simple pdf files. Both files contain a single line of text ("ZYXWVUTSRQQRSTUVWXYZ") and were created on Mac OS X.

The first file was created with TextEdit. There are only three streams, and looking at the first one (automatically decoded with peepdf) shows the text clearly.

```
PPDF> stream 4

q Q q 72 707.272 468 12.72803 re W n /Cs1 cs 0 sc q 0.9790795 0 0 -0.9790795 72 720
cm BT 0.0001 Tc 11 0 0 -11 5 10 Tm /TT1 1 Tf (ZYXWVUTSRQQRSTUVWXYZ) Tj ET
Q Q
```

The second file was created with MS Word. There are four streams but the decoded text is no where to be found. Looking at the corresponding stream in the Word doc does not reveal the decoded string:

```
PPDF> stream 4

q Q q 18 40 576 734 re W n /Cs1 cs 0 0 0 sc q 0.24 0 0 0.24 90 708.72 cm BT
-0.0004 Tc 50 0 0 50 0 0 Tm /TT2 1 Tf [ (!") -1 (#) -1 ($) -1 (%&'\() -1 (\))
-1 (*) -1 (*) -1 (\)) -1 (\() -1 ('&%$) -1 (#) -1 (") -1 (!) ] TJ ET Q q 0.24 0 0 0.24 239.168 708.72
cm BT 50 0 0 50 0 0 Tm /TT2 1 Tf (+) Tj ET Q Q
```

It's not apparent to me where the string is in the file or what the information in this stream means. Any insights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's not apparent to me where the string is in the file

In general you won't see the clear text in the content stream because the encoding used there needs not be a standard encoding, nothing ASCII'ish.

```
[ (!") -1 (#) -1 ($) -1 (%&'\() -1 (\)) -1 (*) -1 (*) -1 (\)) -1 (\() -1 ('&%$) -1 (#) -1 (") -1 (!) ] TJ
```

This operation in its array operand contains your `ZYXWVUTSRQQRSTUVWXYZ` with some kerning corrections for certain pairs of characters.

It looks like an ad hoc encoding using the bytes from 33 (= 0x21 = '!') onwards. '!' is used for the first glyph needed, the ***Z***, '"' for the second one needed ***Y***, '#' for the third one ***X***, etc. Your test string not only starts with these chars but also ends with them, and so does the array above, `(!") -1 (#)` ... `(#) -1 (") -1 (!)`.

Inspect the definition of the font used (**TT2**). It may (or may not) include information helping you decoding this encoding.

> or what the information in this stream means. Any insights?

To understand the contents of PDF content streams, you should read the relevant sections of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), especially chapters 8 *Graphics* and 9 *Text*.

As your question is focused on the recognition of text content, e.g. read section 9.10.2 *Mapping Character Codes to Unicode Values*:

> A conforming reader can use these methods, in the priority given, to map a character code to a Unicode value. Tagged PDF documents, in particular, shall provide at least one of these methods (see 14.8.2.4.2, "Unicode Mapping in Tagged PDF"):
>
> - If the font dictionary contains a **ToUnicode** CMap (see 9.10.3, "ToUnicode CMaps"), use that CMap to convert the character code to Unicode.
> - If the font is a simple font that uses one of the predefined encodings **MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**, or that has an encoding whose **Differences** array includes only character names taken from the Adobe standard Latin character set and the set of named characters in the Symbol font (see Annex D):
>
>   a) Map the character code to a character name according to Table D.1 and the font’s **Differences** array.
>
>   b) Look up the character name in the *Adobe Glyph List* (see the Bibliography) to obtain the corresponding Unicode value.
> - If the font is a composite font that uses one of the predefined CMaps listed in Table 118 (except Identity–H and Identity–V) or whose descendant CIDFont uses the Adobe-GB1, Adobe-CNS1, Adobe-Japan1, or Adobe-Korea1 character collection:
>
>   a) Map the character code to a character identifier (CID) according to the font’s CMap.
>
>   b) Obtain the registry and ordering of the character collection used by the font’s CMap (for example, Adobe and Japan1) from its **CIDSystemInfo** dictionary.
>
>   c) Construct a second CMap name by concatenating the registry and ordering obtained in step (b) in the format *registry–ordering*–UCS2 (for example, Adobe–Japan1–UCS2).
>
>   d) Obtain the CMap with the name constructed in step (c) (available from the ASN Web site; see the Bibliography).
>
>   e) Map the CID obtained in step (a) according to the CMap obtained in step (d), producing a Unicode value.
>
> NOTE Type 0 fonts whose descendant CIDFonts use the Adobe-GB1, Adobe-CNS1, Adobe-Japan1, or Adobe-Korea1 character collection (as specified in the CIDSystemInfo dictionary) shall have a supplement number corresponding to the version of PDF supported by the conforming reader. See Table 3 for a list of the character collections corresponding to a given PDF version. (Other supplements of these character collections can be used, but if the supplement is higher-numbered than the one corresponding to the supported PDF version, only the CIDs in the latter supplement are considered to be standard CIDs.)
>
> If these methods fail to produce a Unicode value, there is no way to determine what the character code represents in which case a conforming reader may choose a character code of their choosing.

**Edit:** *Concerning the comment*

> One of the objects gave some font info. It is 'JJOWGO+Cambria' and references object 16 as the 'font file' which was also unreadable. I'll review the manual. Can't find anything online about 'JJOWGO'.

You wont find anything specific about `JJOWGO` because it most likely is a random key sequence prefixed to `Cambria` to indicate that not all of that font is embedded but only a subset. Cf. section 9.6.4 *Font Subsets* of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> PDF documents may include subsets of Type 1 and TrueType fonts. The font and font descriptor that describe a font subset are slightly different from those of ordinary fonts. These differences allow a conforming reader to recognize font subsets and to merge documents containing different subsets of the same font. (For more information on font descriptors, see 9.8, "Font Descriptors".)
>
> For a font subset, the PostScript name of the font—the value of the font’s **BaseFont** entry and the font descriptor’s **FontName** entry— shall begin with a tag followed by a plus sign (+). The tag shall consist of exactly six uppercase letters; the choice of letters is arbitrary, but different subsets in the same PDF file shall have different tags.
>
> EXAMPLE EOODIA+Poetica is the name of a subset of Poetica®, a Type 1 font.

```
 <<
 /FontBBox [ -1475 -2463 2867 3117 ]
 /StemV 0
 /FontFile2 16 0 R
 /Descent -222
 /XHeight 467
 /Flags 4
 /Ascent 950
 /FontName /JJOWGO+Cambria
 /Type /FontDescriptor
 /ItalicAngle 0
 /AvgWidth 615
 /MaxWidth 2919
 /CapHeight 667
 >>
```

This font descriptor contains no obvious encoding information. Have a look at the actual **Font** dictionary and look for a **ToUnicode** entry, cf. the quotation of section 9.10.2 above.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. One of the objects gave some font info. It is 'JJOWGO+Cambria' and references object 16 as the 'font file' which was also unreadable. I'll review the manual. Can't find anything online about 'JJOWGO'.

<< /FontBBox [ -1475 -2463 2867 3117 ]
/StemV 0
/FontFile2 16 0 R
/Descent -222
/XHeight 467
/Flags 4
/Ascent 950
/FontName /JJOWGO+Cambria
/Type /FontDescriptor
/ItalicAngle 0
/AvgWidth 615
/MaxWidth 2919
/CapHeight 667 >>

Answer (score 3):

Comments from @mkl made it clear what is happening. The text in the pdf produced by MS Word was using a character map.

I tracked down the font dictionary by searching for objects with a ToUnicode entry:

```
<< /FirstChar 33
/Widths [ 538 570 571 921 604 648 593 496 621 653 220 ]
/Type /Font
/BaseFont /JJOWGO+Cambria
/LastChar 43
/Subtype /TrueType
/FontDescriptor 13 0 R
/ToUnicode 14 0 R >>
```

The ToUnicode entry referenced object 14, so I looked at that next:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo <<
  /Registry (Adobe)
  /Ordering (UCS)
  /Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00><FF>
endcodespacerange
1 beginbfchar
<2b><0009 000d 0020 00a0>
endbfchar
10 beginbfrange
<21><21><005a>
<22><22><0059>
<23><23><0058>
<24><24><0057>
<25><25><0056>
<26><26><0055>
<27><27><0054>
<28><28><0053>
<29><29><0052>
<2a><2a><0051>
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

Section 9.10.3 of ISO 32000-1 explains how beginbfrange maps character ranges to each other. Ranges of character codes are mapped to Unicode values. The "range" 21-21 contains a single character, which is "!". It is mapped to U+005a ("Z"). The mapping contains a line for every character in my test document, from Z to Q. (! to *)